# CollectionView Error [swift]

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Sometimes i will get error from my collectionview, here is the code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubCategoryDetailsCollectionViewCell

    let grey = UIColor(red: 85.0/255.0, green: 85.0/255.0, blue: 85.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cell.layer.borderColor = grey.CGColor

    cell.titleLabel.text = name[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: thumbImg1[indexPath.row] ))
```

Error occur at this line

```
    cell.productLabel.text = label[indexPath.row]

    if promo[indexPath.row] == "0"{
        cell.priceLabel.hidden = true
        cell.promoLabel.text = "RM" + price[indexPath.row]
        cell.promoLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    }else{
        cell.priceLabel.hidden = false
        cell.promoLabel.text = "RM" + promo[indexPath.row]
        cell.priceLabel.text = "RM" + price[indexPath.row]
        cell.promoLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: (cell.priceLabel.text)!)
        attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
        cell.priceLabel.attributedText = attributeString
    }


    cell.productLabel.text = label[indexPath.row]

    cell.setNeedsDisplay()
    return cell


}
```

fatal error: Index out of range

Why is it? Sometimes it will work just fine, but sometimes not. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `indexPath.row` is greater than the length of your `label` array.  You may be creating more cells than you need. Check how many cells you are creating in your `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int)` method.

Try returning the number of cells equal to the length of your label array and that might fix your issue.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return label.count
}
```

Comment: it have a error "cannot convert return expression of type 'int' to return type 'uicollectionviewcell'"

Comment: You have two collectionview delegate methods you need to put in your code, one returns `Int` (x number of cells to create in the collectionview) and the other returns a  'UICollectionViewCell' (method is called x times to format all cells).


`collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`
and
`collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int`

I think your error is because you put `return label.count` into the first method and not the second.

Comment: Simply put, return your code back to the way it was and just cut and paste my code example in the answer somewhere into your swift file.